# How to add customer details for guest user using Magento rest API - create order

Tags: magento2, rest-api, create-order

I am creating an order for a guest user using Magento rest API.

Approach:

1. Create a quote
2. Add items to the cart
3. Prepare checkout - Adding billing and shipping information for the order
4. Create an order - Adding payment information while creating order

I am following the above steps to create order, When I do the final step its showing error customer email is missing.

```
URL: 
/rest/V1/carts/10/order
Payload: {

"paymentMethod": {
"method": "checkmo"
}
}

Response:
{
    "message": "The customer email is missing. Enter and try again."
}
```

How to add customer details in guest user order?

Please do need full for this scenario

Answer (score 2):

> Create order for guest customer using Rest API

**Get the admin token:**

EndPoint : http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

Method : POST

Headers:

Content-Type : application/json

Body json:-

```
{"username":"API_USER","password":"API_PASSWORD"}
```

Response:-

```
16fsjy4242fssdsfsxipegpr9gpxf7p2424bx91sbbje0mg
```

This token will be used for the further steps while creating order through api.

**Create empty cart for the guest customer :**

EndPoint : http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/

Method : POST

Headers:-

Content-Type : application/json

Authorization : Bearer {TOKEN}

It will return a alphanumeric string, which is the cart id, this will be used to `add/update/delete` items form the cart.

**Add/Update items in cart :**

Endpoint : http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items

i.e. http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/4522ebc7d219rre415a8ad1eewr22f73b55/items

Method : POST

Headers:

Content-Type : application/json

Authorization : Bearer {TOKEN}

Body json:

```
{ "cartItem": { "quote_id": "4522ebc7d219rre415a8ad1eewr22f73b55", "sku": "Item SKU", "qty": 1 } }
```

Note :- It will return the item_id which can be used later to update/delete item from the cart.
To update shopping item use the following request in body json on the same endpoint as above :-

```
{ "cartItem": { "quote_id": "4522ebc7d219rre415a8ad1eewr22f73b55", "item_id": 1139, "sku": "Item SKU", "qty": 2 } }
```

**Add shipping information to the cart :**

EndPoint : http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/shipping-information

Method : POST

Headers:

Content-Type : application/json

Authorization : Bearer {TOKEN}

Body json :-

```
{ "addressInformation": { "shippingAddress": { "country_id": "US", "street": [ "Street Address" ], "company": "Company", "telephone": "2313131312", "postcode": "", "city": "California", "firstname": "john", "lastname": "harrison", "email": "guestuser@gmail.com", "sameAsBilling": 1 }, "billingAddress": { "country_id": "US", "street": [ "Street Address" ], "company":"Company", "telephone": "2313131312", "postcode": "", "city": "California", "firstname": "john", "lastname": "harrison", "email": "guestuser@gmail.com" }, "shipping_method_code": "flatrate", "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate" } }
```

> Note :- Here flatrate is the shipping method code, you can change
>   whatever shipping method you are using for your store. It will return
>   the payment methods available with entire cart information.

Response :-

```
{ "payment_methods": [ { "code": "checkmo", "title": "Check / Money Order" } ], "totals": { "grand_total": 40.5, "base_grand_total": 40.5, "subtotal": 40, "base_subtotal": 40, "discount_amount": 0, "base_discount_amount": 0, "subtotal_with_discount": 40, "base_subtotal_with_discount": 40, "shipping_amount": 0.5, "base_shipping_amount": 0.5, "shipping_discount_amount": 0, "base_shipping_discount_amount": 0, "tax_amount": 0, "base_tax_amount": 0, "weee_tax_applied_amount": null, "shipping_tax_amount": 0, "base_shipping_tax_amount": 0, "subtotal_incl_tax": 40, "shipping_incl_tax": 0.5, "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0.5, "base_currency_code": "USD", "quote_currency_code": "USD", "items_qty": 2, "items": [ { "item_id": 14437, "price": 10, "base_price": 10, "qty": 2, "row_total": 40, "base_row_total": 40, "row_total_with_discount": 0, "tax_amount": 0, "base_tax_amount": 0, "tax_percent": 0, "discount_amount": 0, "base_discount_amount": 0, "discount_percent": 0, "price_incl_tax": 10, "base_price_incl_tax": 10, "row_total_incl_tax": 40, "base_row_total_incl_tax": 40, "options": "[]", "weee_tax_applied_amount": null, "weee_tax_applied": null, "name": "Baby Bag" } ], "total_segments": [ { "code": "subtotal", "title": "Subtotal", "value": 40 }, { "code": "flatrate", "title": "Flat Rate", "value": 0.5 }, { "code": "tax", "title": "Tax", "value": 0, "extension_attributes": { "tax_grandtotal_details": [] } }, { "code": "grand_total", "title": "Grand Total", "value": 40.5, "area": "footer" } ] } }
```

**Add payment information and place the order :**

EndPoint : http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/order

Method : PUT

Headers:

Content-Type : application/json

Authorization : Bearer {TOKEN}

Body json:-

```
{ "paymentMethod": { "method": "checkmo" } }
```

It will return the order id, now you can check the order has been created in the admin.

Reference: https://github.com/rakeshmagento/magento2-create-order-for-guest-customer-rest-api#1-get-the-admin-token--

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I followed the same steps for order creation but the final step it's showing error - customer email is missing.